# Focus out of a textbox on datepicker change

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to focus out of a textbox when the user is in the process of selecting a date from the datepicker.
HTML

```
<input id="startDate" class="datepicker rounded hasDatepicker" type="text" name="startDate" readonly="">
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="images/calendar_icon.png" alt="...">
```

The script I tried.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        $("#startDate").blur();
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#startDate").focusin();
    }
});​
```

Please help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does your current code do wrong?

Comment: this code isn't focusing out the pointer from the text box during the process of selecting a date from the datepicker. i want that it should focus out when selecting.whether it focuses back in or not onselect isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the **beforeShow** and onClose event in your code...

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShow:function(input, inst){$(this).css('color','white')},
        onClose:function(dateText, inst){$(this).css('color','black')}
    });
});
```

But remember... **Known issue: Datepicker does not trigger a create event.**

Source: [jQuery UI datepicker#event-beforeShow](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShow)

---

**EDITED** with new option:

**HTML Example**

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly">​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){$('#datepicker').datepicker()});
```

​Example in: http://jsfiddle.net/nNPJS/2/

Comment: thnx @gmo.
this helped a lot. but if i select a date once and then try to change it again,i should be able to see what date i had entered earlier.

Comment: Then, is no need to change the color, just use readonly to the input field, ex: http://jsfiddle.net/nNPJS/1/ Is this what you want?

Comment: no,even in this,even though the text box is disabled you can still see the cursor blinking every time you click on next/previous in the datepicker.disabling the textbox isn't a priority,but rather that the textbox should lose focus on opening the date picker,i.e. the cursor shouldn't be visible in the textbox when i am using the date picker.

Comment: Doesn't happened to me in chrome. But then you need a cross browser solution. I think a good hack with css could be the solution, as for example, have two inputs and the main one hidden, the visible one only show the value... Let me know if you want to try more options. cheers.